# How can I efficiently populate a data frame with an index variable and two random variables?

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, random

I have written a dataframe with 3 variables: x,y and z with the following characteristics:

1) The dataframe contains 10 sets of x and y variables drawn at random from a standard normal distribution.
2) Each set, denoted as z, has 10 observations of x, y pairs.

```
df1<-data.frame(x=rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10),z=1)
df2<-data.frame(x=rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10),z=2)
df3<-data.frame(x=rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10),z=3)
df4<-data.frame(x=rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10),z=4)
df5<-data.frame(x=rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10),z=5)
df6<-data.frame(x=rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10),z=6)
df7<-data.frame(x=rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10),z=7)
df8<-data.frame(x=rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10),z=8)
df9<-data.frame(x=rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10),z=9)
df10<-data.frame(x=rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10),z=10)
```

then I bind the rows in one dataframe

```
df<bind_rows(df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,df6,df7,df8,df9,df10)
```

I have tried to do this using the following for loop:

```
for (i in seq(1,10,1)) {
  df<-data.frame(x="",y="",z="")
  df<-rbind(data.frame(x=rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10),z=i))
}
```

but I am unable to make the z-index variable to increase each 10 rows and bind the data generated 10 times. The z variable remains constant and equal to 10

Is there anything I have to modify in the loop or other options to do this?

Comment: `do.call(rbind,lapply(1:10,function(z)data.frame(x=rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10),z)))` or since all the x and y come from rnorm, you could also do: `data.frame(x=rnorm(100),y=rnorm(100),z=rep(1:10,each=10))`

Comment: In your `for` loop solution there are three errors. 1) The initial `df` must be initialized outside the loop 2) Variables have to be `numeric` instead of strings as you did. The correct initialization is `df<-data.frame(x=numeric(0),y=numeric(0),z=numeric(0))`. 3) inside the loop you have to `rbind` the previous results with the new one: `df<-rbind(df, data.frame(x=rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10),z=i))`. That said, using a `for` loop is suboptimal, slow and memory inefficient here and you should use what @Onyambu suggested.

Comment: @Onyambu and Nicola thank you very much for your help! I did not know the do.call() and rep() functions.